# How can I access the same text area variable?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

The code below works as such:

- User clicks the run button
- Program reads the file from designated location
- Program removes content from `<script> </script>`, including tags themselves
- Program returns edited text into `JTextArea` called `textArea`

I've tried making it a global variable since it's in two different classes. The run down is that once the user clicks the "run button", the text area initialised in the GUI class will update.

```
public class GUI{
        static JTextArea textArea;
    public GUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        textArea = new JTextArea(5,30);
        JButton runButton = new JButton("Remove JS");
        JButton importButton = new JButton("Import File");
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        
        runButton.addActionListener(new runApp());
        runButton.setBounds(100, 100, 100, 80);
        importButton.addActionListener(new importFile());
        importButton.setBounds(100, 100, 80, 60);
        
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(300, 300 , 150, 150));
        panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1));
        panel.add(textArea);
        panel.add(runButton);
        panel.add(importButton);
        
        frame.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setTitle("JavaScript Extractor");
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new GUI();

    }
}

class runApp implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        
        RemoveScript run = new RemoveScript();
        

        try {
            File fileObject = new File("C:\\Users\\coker\\Documents\\readJS.txt");
            Scanner reader = new Scanner(fileObject);
            while(reader.hasNextLine()) {
                String output = reader.nextLine();
                textArea.setText(run.removeScript(output));
            }
            reader.close();
        }catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("An error has occured.");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Some information was removed from the original post, what the program is removing are javascript script tags and it ruturns the file's contents without them. This is the line giving an error" "textArea.setText(run.removeScript(output));"

Comment: What's the error and stacktracke? I suggest splitting the problematic line into 2 separate instructions to learn which one causes the error.

Comment: "textArea cannot be resolved" and it's giving me the option to create a local variable of textArea, but i'm sure it's going to create another JTextArea, which isn't what I want. I would just like it to know that i'm referencing "textArea"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

3 options:

- Make your listener class an inner class of `GUI`, then it will have access to all fields of it's outer class (no need for static in that case)
- Keep the 2 classes completely separate, and pass a reference to the text field to the listener (e.g. via constructor parameter).
- access the static field via `GUI.textArea`

Comment: Just implemented what you've said and it worked, thank you Reto.

Comment: Don't use a static variable. There is no need and it is poor design, that is NOT how a static variable should be used.